# JDialog box giving same result for both yes and no buttons/inputs

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdialog

I have created a JDialog box to display some warning massage to the users. When the user gets the warning massage and if he clicks on yes button the application do some work and if the user selects no then he remains on the same place.
I am getting 0 value for yes and 1 value for no. But the JDialog box giving same result for both yes and no button i.e, application is getting close for both inputs. But what i wanted is if the user selects yes then the application do some thing and if he selects no then nothing happen(the UI window remain open).

```
public void warningMassage(String Text) {
    int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, Text, "Warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    System.out.println(n);
    if(n == 0){
        System.exit(0);
        System.out.println(JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    } else {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}//warningMassage
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, copilable, because someone (not by mistake) can take this question asa joke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code

```
public void warningMassage(String yourText){
    int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
            frame,
            yourText,
            "Warning",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    System.out.println(n);
      if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
          frame.setVisible(true);
      }
      else{
          System.exit(0);
          System.out.println(JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
      }
}//warningMassage
```

A YES returns 0 and a NO returns 1

[Documentation for the JDialog Box](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if(n==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    //yes pressed
else
    //no pressed
```

Answer (score 1):

JDialog box is **not**  giving same result for both **yes** and **no** inputs 
.  if  you choose **No**  the frame does not close untill you press

[image: To close Jframe]

on **terminal** or you explicitly set

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

As said by @Cool Guy I also prefer to use

```
if(n==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    //yes pressed
else
    //no pressed
```

but currently at this time your problem is not this .Do Post your Main Class

Answer (score 0):

`JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()` with *`JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION`* can return:

- *`JOptionPane.YES_OPTION`*: *public static final int YES_OPTION = 0;*
- *`JOptionPane.NO_OPTION`*: *public static final int NO_OPTION = 1;*

You should use those const in your check:

```
if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    // do something
}
```

However, a small *hint*: if you want to display a *warning message*, consider to use this:

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
    parentComponent,
    message,
    title,
    optionType,
    messageType
);
```

where *messageType* is an integer designating the kind of message this is; primarily used to determine the icon from the pluggable Look and Feel: *ERROR_MESSAGE*, *INFORMATION_MESSAGE*, *WARNING_MESSAGE*, *QUESTION_MESSAGE*, or *PLAIN_MESSAGE*.

Then, in your case:

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
    null,
    "message",
    "TITLE",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE// <--- !!
);
```

[image: Warning JOptionPane]